# Is it possible to restrict the Event publisher to send specific Event Types in Azure Event Grid?

Tags: azure-eventgrid

I know that we can create Event Grid subscriptions based on event type filters. Similarly is it possible to restrict the event publisher to send only specific event types. Otherwise we have to build a custom Event Service which has to check whether publisher is authorized to publish the specific event type or not. If the publisher is authorized then the Event Service has to publish the event to the Event Grid. This is an unnecessary router service.

At this moment I am thinking of building an event authorization service which will provide the SAS token based on the Event Types for the publisher. Any other solution?

Comment: In the Pub/Sub eventing model you always subscribe to the interest source. You have a full control over the event subscriptions. Could you give a specific use case for your scenario?

Comment: @RomanKiss Let us assume i am building an event mediator service and this will be used by multiple products within the Enterprise. In this case if we wanted to register the publisher with Event Service and do the authorization to allow specific event types to publish.

Comment: The Azure Event Grid is not a generic Pub/Sub Eventing model. Its event sources are built-in the azure resource groups entities with a predefined topic and event types. However,  there are the custom topics (max 20 per region) where can be managed by the users. In other words, these custom topics can be used for your event mediators. Note, that the firing a custom topic with a wrong 'topic' property in the event message such as is not null/empty or custom topic value will generate an error 401

Comment: Thanks @RomanKiss. I am using Custom Topics to build this service. It would be better to have this feature in the Event Grid itself otherwise we have to build a mediator service which is unnecessary routing service.

Comment: you can submit your idea to https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909934-azure-event-grid/filters/new